# Liskov Substitution Principle Confusion

Tags: oop, liskov-substitution-principle

I am confused about the intent of the LSP.
I am reading the Pragmatic Programmer and in the design, by contract chapter, this line appears in reference to LSP.

*Subclasses must be usable through the base class interface without the need for the user to know the difference.*

But if I look at other definitions and SO it seems to suggest the exact inverse that in fact it's the subclass that should be able to stand in for the base class.

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two ways to say the same thing.

Inheritance is a greatly abused concept, but I believe the simplest way not to screw the design of a system is to consider it that way:

Inheritance means that the subclass *is a* base class. With that in mind:

> Subclasses must be usable through the base class interface without the need for the user to know the difference.

If you extend a class, the subclass must be able to replace the base class. A script must be able to use the subclass as it would use the base class without failling.

> it seems to suggest the exact inverse that in fact it's the subclass that should be able to stand in for the base class.

Simple confusion, that means the same thing. The subclass must be able to replace the base class.

---

In more details:

> Subclasses must be usable through the base class interface [...]

The base class interface consists of its contract. The base class defines an api through which it can be used. For instance, a base class `Number` could feature a `public method add(Number $number)`.

Any and every extending class (such as `Integer`) must be able to be used as any `Number` would, without having to modify the code that deals with the numbers.

Comment: So in summary, make sure you keep method names consistent between base and subclasses and ensure any changes to the method logic of a subclass doesn't fundamentally change the intention of the method of the base class?

But one if free to extend sub classes with additional methods?